# Cross-Protocol share on 3PAR File Persona

Tags: 3par

We have 3PAR 8200's in each of our data centers.  I don't play with them much, only when I have to.

I'm trying to create a cross-protocol (NFS+SMB read/write) using the SSMC.  While I've created the share, Neither Windows nor Linux can write to it.  The Linux nodes connect to AD using PBIS (formerly LikeWise).

What I need is to allow only "Domain Users" access to the share, either SMB for Windows or NFS for Linux.

I've read through File Persona User Guide but I've not been able to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't work on 3Pars for a while, but if the OS does detect the allocated space from 3Par you then should have absolutely no problem putting any access rights on that.

Comment: Thanks but it works fine from Windows but not Linux, and Linux is the more important platform for us.